# How to exchange values between two main methods

Tags: java, rpc

I have a main method in class 'A' which is updating a variable every 20 sec . Now i have to get the updated value of this variable in some other main method of class B. I am avoiding use of database. I have tried using static setter and getter but getting null values .Please help .

Class A and class B are running in two JVMs

Comment: why cant your have a property get method? or is your question on how to do it in struts? If so yo need to be more specific in your question and show what you have done so far

Comment: run `A` and `B` in different `Thread`s and pass your `A` instance to your `B` instance and let `B` call `A`'s getter for your variable

Comment: i have tried static setter and getter but getting null values.

Comment: you need first to read a programming tutorial about processes (OS process) & memory and Java tutorial on EJB and IO (URLs). If you have two Jvms you need a way for one to ask theother its value via remote call (Ejb or http post etc)

Comment: is your class A running in a container like jboss or is it a stand alone application whose main you call?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, if you were in a container I would have suggested EJB or a plain servlet that replies with the value when its called via a URL.

---

For a standalone app you can expose a web service it is 2-3 annotations and can use the java inbuilt EndPoint class to make and expose the service.

have a seperate class as the web service, right now it will have only one method getAValue() : int

Later can add to this is required.

See http://java.dzone.com/articles/jax-ws-hello-world or http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbor.html

Remember to have a way of changing the IP address/ URL for production (Properties file/ db init whatever)

---

You can also use a data base but this would be slower. A would update data base - can have a simple table with key and values - now need to update one row where key = "ClassAVal1" or similar, clients would read from here